# Changing a service endpoint address in my web.config with XML Transformation

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, transformation

I've got two endpoint addresses associated with my service, and I want to change both of them in my Web.Release.config. I haven't worked with XML transformations before so I'm unsure of how to do this, especially for cases when there are more than one endpoint addresses that need to be changed.

I have found other examples on Stackoverflow, but the XML structure for those is different than what I have.

```
</configuration>

   <system.serviceModel>

      <services>

        <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.ServiceBehavior" name="MyService.Documents">
           <endpoint name="MyService.Documents.Endpoint"
                address="https://MyApp.net/Documents.svc"
                behaviorConfiguration="MyService.EndpointBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
                contract="MyService.IDocuments" />
        </service>

        <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.ServiceBehavior" name="MyService.Leads">
           <endpoint name="MyService.Leads.Endpoint"
                address="https://MyApp.net/Leads.svc"
                behaviorConfiguration="MyService.EndpointBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
                contract="MyService.ILeads" />
        </service>

     </services>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

The two endpoint addresses **https://MyApp.net/Documents.svc** and **https://MyApp.net/Leads.svc** are what I need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's the transformation I came up with.

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

    <system.serviceModel>

        <services>

            <service name="MyService.Documents">
                <endpoint name="MyService.Documents.Endpoint" 
                    address="https://MyApp-sandbox.net/Documents.svc"
                    xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
                    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(address)"/>
            </service>

            <service name="MyService.Leads">
                <endpoint name="MyService.Leads.Endpoint"
                    address="https://MyApp-sandbox.net/Leads.svc"
                    xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
                    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(address)"/>
            </service>

        </services>

    </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```